# <pre> is displaying MySQL text as like without <pre> in TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf

I want like to surround text from MySQL in `<pre>` tags. Here is my code -

```
$html=$html.'<pre>'.$database[$i]['response'].'</pre>';
```

But when viewed in a browser, it is not behaving as expected, as there are no new lines and spacing is not preserved.

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

The `<pre>` tag will works fine in TCPDF, please try this,

```
$html .='<pre> '.$database[$i]['response'].' </pre>';
```

Or

```
$html .='<pre> echo $database[$i]['response'] </pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade your `TCPDF` library it will start working.

[You can see more pre tag example in TCPDF here](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/main/examples/example_006.php)

**Note:** `<pre>` tag will not work inside `<td>` tag.